# Can non admin users get list of google calendar resources?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk

I understand that the list of rooms (google calendar resources) can only be accessed using the Calendar Resources API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/).  But, it seems that domain admins credentials are needed to access it.  Is there a way for non-admin users to get a list of all rooms using the API, similar to what they can get from the google calendar web UI by selecting 'add rooms'?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the calendar resource API does allow non-admin accounts to list the resources.  The issue I was running into was that the API access had not been enabled on that Google Apps account.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. This is a bummer. I hit the same issue and couldn't find a workaround other than adding the shared resource calendars to your own personal list of calendars and then you can use https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list to pull them that way. This means that you have to manually add any calendar resources you want pull info for though.

I've written an app to pull events for our conference room resources in google apps and it would be great for a user to choose which room they wanted to show events for when the app started rather than hardcoding calendar resource IDs like we currently are.

It would likely make the most sense to add something to the google calendars API to pull a list of resources rather than just keep that functionality in the admin-sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to user3591271's answer, Calendar Resources API requires a Super Admin, you can't have any less.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use the Calendar Resources API from the Admin SDK (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/list) without admin privileges, despite the documentation implying otherwise.